# Less media-query variable returns ParseError: Expected ')'

Tags: less, media-queries

I just started using Less and now I'm trying to convert my media query into a variable. What I want is this:

```
@mobile: only screen and (max-width: 750px);
@media @mobile;{
    body {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

But when I run my website it returns the following error:

> ParseError: Expected ')' in main.less on line 1, column 27:
>
> 1 - @mobile: only screen and (max-width: 750px);

What am I doing wrong? :-(

Comment: There are a couple of pretty minor errors and so I am undecided on whether to post as answer or comment. (1) Remove the `;` after `@media @mobile` - that is not required. (2) For the `@mobile` variable, enclose the value within `~""` (like `~"only screen..."`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
@mobile: ~"only screen and (max-width: 750px)";
@media @mobile {
    body {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, that's not it. This one returns the 'ParseError: media definitions require block statements after any features' error

Comment: @MvanOeffel ... Just compiled and checked on Winless Complier getting no error's.

Comment: @MvanOeffel - then you either not really tested the proper code or being using some exotic non-conformant compiler (barely since the code is one of the oldest Less code snippets - and should work just anywhere). [Demo](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22%40mobile%3A%20~%5C%22only%20screen%20and%20(max-width%3A%20750px)%5C%22%3B%5Cn%40media%20%40mobile%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20body%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font-size%3A%2030px%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D).

Comment: @MvanOeffel - in fact the error message hints that you still tried `@media @mobile;{ ...` instead of the proper `@media @mobile { ...`